# Headers se envian sin problemas aún después de enviar una salida

Tags: php, headers

En este quisiera lograr lo contrario, no hay errores, quiero generarlos. Estoy estudiando el uso de las funciones ob_* de PHP. Encontré este código para entender los conceptos, y se supone que debería lanzar un error, pues entiendo que una vez se envie una salida, las cabeceras ya no pueden ser  modificadas, o configurar las sesiones o cookies. Si alguien puede aclararme el por qué todo fluye sin problema?

```
  <?php
    //ob_start();

echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">';

?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Página procesada con buffer de salida</title>
</head>

<body>
    Esta es mi página!!!
</body>

</html>
<?php

setcookie("nombre", "john");
//ob_end_flush(); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguramente en tu servidor tienes activado un [búfer o control de salida](https://www.php.net/manual/es/outcontrol.configuration.php); el comportamiento se puede modificar en `php.ini` o en tiempo de ejecución, dependiendo de las características del servidor; recuerda que servidores compartidos rara vez permiten estos cambios.

Hay dos variables importantes:

- **output_buffering**: Aunque el manual menciona que el valor por defecto es cero, la mayoría de las veces tiene la cantidad de bytes que se deben acumular en el búfer antes de enviarlo al navegador (o salida estándar). En mi servidor local, sin haber modificado, tiene 4096.
- **implicit_flush**: El valor por defecto es `off` y, cuando se coloca en `on`, toda salida es enviada inmediatamente al navegador (o salida estándar).

Edita el archivo `php.ini` correspondiente a tu versión de PHP (y reinicia el servidor) o configura en tiempo de ejecución con [ini_set('variable', 'nuevo valor');](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php), estableciendo `output_buffering` en cero e `implicit_flush` en `on`.

En teoría, con esto se debe enviar cualquier salida inmediatamente y tu script debería mostrar errores, por supuesto, siempre y cuando tengas activada también esa opción; caso contrario, revisa la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php) para configurar los errores que quieras mostrar.

### Observación importante:

Es muy buena idea hacer estas pruebas para depuración, pero recuerda volver a poner los valores originales cuando tu proyecto esté en producción, de lo contrario, puede haber problemas de rendimiento.